# Determine if $ \sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\ln n}}$ congerges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine if the following series converges:

$$ \sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\ln n}}.$$

I'm supposed to use here the limit comparison test, but I don't know how to choose the second series.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that $ \ln n < n$, so that $\sqrt[n]{\ln n} < n$, so that
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\ln n}} > \frac{1}{n}.$$

Direct comparison of these two series now shows the first to diverge. $\diamondsuit$

Answer (score 0):

For $n>2$,
$$1 < \ln(n) < n,$$
so that
$$\sqrt[n]{1} < \sqrt[n]{\ln(n)} < \sqrt[n]{n}.$$
By the squeeze theorem, as $n \to \infty$,  $\sqrt[n]{\ln(n)} \to 1$. Since the reciprocal also tends to 1, the series diverges by the $n$'th term test.